# Value below was evaluated just now in console.log after trying to log this.state updated values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to log my updated this.state with the new values xRotation, yRotation and zRotation. But when i try to log this.state.x, this.state.y, this.state.z i get to see this icon with the message: Value below was evaluated just now. I thought applying async await to the connect() function and navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({}) would fix my problem but it didn't.

```
connect = async () => {

  let x = {};
  let y = {};
  let z = {};
  let currentStateX = this.state.x;
  let currentStateY = this.state.y;
  let currentStateZ = this.state.z;

  await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
      // filters: [myFilters]       // you can't use filters and acceptAllDevices together
      optionalServices: [myService],
      acceptAllDevices: true
  })
  .then((device) => {
      // save the device returned so you can disconnect later:
      myDevice = device;

      // connect to the device once you find it:

      if(!device.gatt.connect()) {
        console.log('no connection')
      } else {
        return  device.gatt.connect(); 
      }
  })
  .then((server) => {
    // get the primary service:
    return  server.getPrimaryService(myService);
  })
  .then((service) => {
      // get the  characteristic:
      return  service.getCharacteristics();

  })
  .then((characteristics) => {

      // subscribe to the characteristic:

        for (let c in characteristics) {
          characteristics[c].startNotifications()
          .then ((characteristic) =>  {
                characteristic.oncharacteristicvaluechanged = (event) => {
                  // get the data buffer from the meter:
                  var xRotation = event.target.value.getFloat32(0,true); 
                  var yRotation = event.target.value.getFloat32(4,true);
                  var zRotation = event.target.value.getFloat32(8,true);

                  x[currentStateX] = xRotation;
                  y[currentStateY] = yRotation;
                  z[currentStateZ] = zRotation;

              }
          });
      } 
  })


  this.setState({ x: x, y: y, z: z});

  console.log(this.state.x);
  console.log(this.state.y);
  console.log(this.state.z);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it would run fine for the rest of the code, because you have awaited it. You have missed one function that's also async and that is `this.setState` if you want to check the values right after it, you will most likely get stale values because the values may not be set yet.

If you want to check the values. `this.setState` has a callback that you can use.

e.g.

```
this.setState({ x: x, y: y, z: z}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.x);
  console.log(this.state.y);
  console.log(this.state.z);
});
```

ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate